# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Nvidia Drivers Not Functional

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, ubuntu-mate

I have an asus laptop with i7 skylake, ssd and nvidia gtx 950m.

Unfortunately for the last two days I am having troubles to use the official drivers. I have used Ubuntu 14 before on various occasions on my old laptop with no problem (though that was ATI), but I am not a power user or something.

My problem is that even though I have the drivers installed, as in this picture:

[image]

Ubuntu still doesn't use them. I don't know why.

When I write `nvidia-settigs` I get this:

[image]

I Think I have problem with x-org, as if the drivers are not in use. I've tried purging the xorg-* but no use and then:

```
install xorg xerver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg
```

I've purge the old drivers, installed new, reinstalled everything - no avail.
I've set the nouevau thing on a blacklist in grub so I think thats ok.

I have constant screen tearing. I think that for the moment computer uses the intel/ati integrated drivers, but I'm not sure.

When try enter `sudo nvidia-xconfig` I get a:

> ```
> Warning:    Unable to locate/open X configuration file. Package xorg-server was not found in ...
> ```

P.S if you know a distro that works out of the box with i7skylake/ATI-integrated + nvidiagtx 950m I would be happy to hear.
I think Ubuntu Mate is a great distro but I think my noob abilities will not be enough to solve this problem.